# API source support in flink

Tags: apache-flink, flink-streaming

Does flink provide a way to poll from an api periodically and create a datastream object out of it for further processing?

We currently push the messages to kafka and read through kafka. Is there any way to poll the api directly through flink?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not aware of such a source connector for Flink, but it would be relatively straightforward to implement one. There are examples out there that do just this but with a database query; one of those might serve as a template for getting started.

Comment: Thanks. Wrote my own custom source function to implement it.